# How can i resize rectangle by dragging its corner in android?

Tags: android

i referred to this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065077/change-size-of-rectangle-by-dragging-its-corners-in-android)

but it only explains concept behind it.
i want to know how to implement it in android.
any help will be appreciated

Comment: You might check out Nguyen's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974088/how-to-create-a-resizable-rectangle-with-user-touch-events-on-android/17807469#17807469

Comment: also you can have a look at android developers guide which gives a good idea: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html